# delete duplicate elements whose type is "object" from a numpy array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Someone knows how to delete duplicate elements from a numpy array whose data type is object ?

For instance,

```
example=array([[
    array([['first', array([[1, 2, 3]]), 1]], dtype=object),
    array([['second', array([[4, 5, 6]]), 2]], dtype=object),
    array([['first', array([[1, 2, 3]]), 1]], dtype=object)]],
  dtype=object)
```

Comment: @Pranav This isn't a feature implementation request, and it's not a debugging question so a [mre] is not applicable. That said, it's not clear if OP has done any research, so some criticism is warranted.

Comment: @wjandrea Any question that says "How do I do X" without showing OP's attempt to do it (or OP's research and a clear explanation of why said research didn't help) is a feature implementation request in my book. Once OP has made an attempt, they should include a MRE if they run into problems.

Comment: @Pranav Fair enough, though calling it a feature is confusing. When I think "feature", I think multiple connected components that make something useful, whereas this should be only one component -- one line of numpy code.

Comment: @wjandrea I guess I should change my canned text to _"Implement this for me"_ :)

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [Find unique rows in numpy.array](/q/16970982/4518341), though I just tried the top answer and it doesn't work for `dtype=object`.

Comment: I suspect you tried `np.unique` and got a "not implemented for object dtype" error.  If so you really should have made this clear.  In any case there isn't a simple `numpy` fix for this.  Those entries can't be sorted, so `unique` can't work. Object dtype arrays are like lists, containing references, not values.  So some sort of iteration (and maybe dict) will be required. @wjandrea

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, yes, I've tried several methods including numpy.unique, and when I used numpy.unique, it showed the error "TypeError: The axis argument to unique is not supported for dtype object". Nevertheless, it seems that there is no other built-in methods which can spend less time  except using the iteration. Thanks for the comments to standardize the question format.